# Closing MdiChild Form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

hi i have a mdi application. in which i have a `mdiparent` which is menu form.Now i have a requisition form.Now when all the deatils hav been filled there is dialogue box which says details filled sucessfully. on the click of Ok in `message box` i am suppose to go back to the `menu page` and also close the requisition form. But th requisition form does not close. ith still remains in the background.
here is the code:

```
private void btnsave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("record saved", "requisition", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                frmmain main = new frmmain();
                main.Show();

                frmrequisition requisition = new frmrequisition();
                requisition.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error", "requisition", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }

}
```

Comment: `frmrequisition requisition = new frmrequisition();            requisition.Close();` what's this? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the requisition form, and calling the close method on that instance:

```
frmrequisition requisition = new frmrequisition();
requisition.Close();
```

You should close the requisition that was being displayed. Have you tried `this.Close()`, assuming the event handler is part of the requisition form?

Comment: yea this.close() worked. but when i am calling               frmmain main = new frmmain();                                main.Show();                                                    what is happening is again another instance of frmmain is getting formed. so there are 2 main forms created. Old 1 and the new 1. how can i get rid of that.

Comment: Take a look at `this.MdiParent`. It should be the parent form. If its not set, then make sure to set it when opening the "requisition form" from the main form

Comment: What I mean is that you should show the existing MdiParent instead of creating a new instance of the main form.

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a new object and closing that. you need to have a reference to your `frmrequisition` that is currently displayed.

Comment: yes thats the same instance i am refering to. See if i dunn create a new object then it says that requisition does not exist. i have created a object frmrequisition on the main form.